# Maven how to depended different version of same libary in one module?

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I have a application need to manage with multiple database version, then came with a painful problem with ElastiSearch. I have to compatible with version of 6.8.0 and 7.8.1. As far as I know that maven didn't supported depend with multiple version of same libary, is anyway to do so?

For my problem, I created a project with tree module "elastic-v6", "elastic-v7" and "elastic-test",
the module of v6 and v7 provide relevant version of elasticsearch operation. In my case it was throught the "RestHighLevelClient" to get indexs.

here is module-v6 maven definition, and v7 is same but with es version of 7.8.1.

```xml
<artifactId>elastic-v6</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

both v6 and v7 module has provide the method "listIndex()".

```java
public static Set<String> listIndex(ElasticEntity entity) {
    try (RestHighLevelClient client = Elastic6Client.buildClient(entity)) {
        GetAliasesRequest request = new GetAliasesRequest();
        GetAliasesResponse getAliasesResponse = client.indices()
                    .getAlias(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        Map<String, Set<AliasMetaData>> map = getAliasesResponse.getAliases();
        return map.keySet();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Here is module "elastic-test" maven definition, but the es version transfer from v7 will override the v6 version(6.8.0). Is anyway that I can load version of 6.8.0 and 7.8.1 whthin "elastic-test" module in the same time.

```xml
<artifactId>elastic-test</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.great</groupId>
        <artifactId>elastic-v7</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.great</groupId>
        <artifactId>elastic-v6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: No. Why do you need to load both versions? I mean, it does not make sense to use more than one version at once.

Comment: my application need to manage with multiple version of es database, my currently solution is use the libray that compatible with both version, or is better way to do so?

Comment: So, do you mean that some users use the newer version of the database and some the older? Or does your application talk to two different versions of the database simultaneously?

Comment: The user have different version of database.

Comment: Are your users programmers who use the library, or are they actual users of the application?

Comment: No, they just user of the application.